# Reusable javascript for User Controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've been working on creating some user controls for ASP.NET web forms application.  It was initially setup with inline javascript similar to the following (See Code Part 1)so that it generated unique id's and functions for each instance of the control.  I inherited the application and I know this wasn't the preferred method as well performance issues with downloading all that extra javascript.

Code Part1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.Application.add_load(loadControl<%=Me.ClientControlId%>);
    function loadControl<%=Me.ClientControlId%>(){
        $("#<%= txtucBankRoutingNbr.ClientID %>").keypress(function(e) { 
            var keyCode = e.which; 
            if (keyCode >= 32 && (keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57))
            { return false; }
            return true;
        });
        $("#<%= txtucBankRoutingNbr.ClientID %>").keydown(function(e) { 
            if (!e)       
                e = window.event;           
            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
            if (code == 123 || code == 45 || code == 27) {
                cancelClick();
                if (e.preventDefault) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                event.cancelBubble = true; 
            }        
        });
        $("#<%= lnkBank.ClientID%>").keypress(function (e) {
            var keyCode = e.which;
            if (keyCode === 13 || keyCode === 32) {
                $.globalEval($("#<%= lnkBank.ClientID %>").attr('href'));
                        return false;
                    }
                        return true;
        });
        Sys.Application.remove_load(loadControl<%=Me.ClientControlId%>);
   }
</script>
```

So based upon some research I deduced that I needed to separate the javascript out into a separate file.  So now we have something like this (Code Part 2 and separate javascript file).  Now this control also contains some controls from Telerik.  Building a Server Control is not an option.

Code Part 2:

```
<script>
    Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
        $create(Company.Controls.ucBankLookup, {
            routingNumber: "#<%=Me.txtucBankRoutingNbr.ClientID%>",
            bankLink: "#<%=Me.lnkBank.ClientID%>"
        }, null, null, $get('<%=Me.ClientID%>'));
        var ctl = $find('<%= Me.ClientID%>');
        ctl.setup();
    });
</script>
```

Separate javascript file:

```
Type.registerNamespace("Company.Controls");
//Constructor
Company.Controls.ucBankLookup = function (element) {
Company.Controls.ucBankLookup.initializeBase(this, [element]);
        this._routingNumber= null;
        this._bankLink= null;
    }

Company.Controls.ucBankLookup.prototype = {
    initialize: function (value) {
        Company.Controls.ucBankLookup.callBaseMethod(this, 'initialize');
    },
    dispose: function () {
        //Add custom dispose actions here
        Company.Controls.ucBankLookup.callBaseMethod(this, 'dispose');
    },
    set_bankLink: function (value) {
        this._bankLink = $(value);
    },
    get_bankLink: function () {
        return this._bankLink;
    },
set_routingNumber: function(value) {
    this._routingNumber= $(value);
},
get_routingNumber: function() {
    return this._routingNumber;
},
    setup: function () {
        var $parent = this;
        //Do somestuff to setup or routing number keypress and keydown events
    }

}
Company.Controls.ucBankLookup.registerClass('Company.Controls.ucBankLookup', Sys.UI.Control);

if (typeof (Sys) !== 'undefined') {
    Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
}
```

So my questions are:

- Is this the correct way to be doing this by passing in the jQuery selectors to the contstructor?
- There seems like there should be a better way to do this.  Is there?  Seems to me that if you need an to get the specific control for the instance of a control that you would need to pass those in and seems like you are moving the mess from one place to another.
- Migrating to MVC is not an option so does anyone else have experience doing these sort of things with web forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time since I've touched WebForms or the Sys stuff on the client-side but regardless of what is used, what you're needing to do with dynamic IDs definitely gets messy with any framework.

I always tried to keep the JavaScript as clean as possible by putting the IDs in one place just liked you have in the second code snippet you shared. That way the main JavaScript that actually does the work can be kept separate which is good for maintenance, caching, etc.

It's messy regardless of what you do, but as long as the bare minimum amount of dynamically generated JavaScript is sent down from the server I think you're fine following the approach you're going with right now. That's how I've always done it.

The only other tactic is to give the bank routing numbers, links, etc. a consistent ID like routeNumber_13245, bankLink_3233 and then write some code on the client-side to extract the IDs based on the consistent prefix, parse out the number, and then process it. That's an option potentially but it really depends on how much control you have over the client-side IDs (predictable ID mode in ASP.NET from what I remember gave some control over that).

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Sounds like I'm headed in the right direction.